How to include Rewarded ads to bind with Python on iOS?
I am currently trying to create a mobile application with rewarded ads and I struggle with the code on XCode.
For now I have already integrated interstitial ads and I would like to adapt the code for rewarded ads.
Here is my current working code for interstitial ads adapted from something found on Github:

UIView *gView;
UIViewController *gViewColtroller;

@interface adInterstitial : NSObject
/// The interstitial ad.
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GADRequest *request;
@end

@implementation adInterstitial

-(id)init {
    [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
    NSLog(@"adInterstitial init");
    return self;
}

- (void)createAndLoadInterstitial {
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"]; // test id
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID, @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a" ];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"createAndLoadInterstitial");
}

- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    //  Method for reloading the object so that you can show ads again
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillDismissScreen");
    [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
}

- (void)InterstitialView {  // show interstitial ADS
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        NSLog(@"Show interstitial ADS!");
        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:rootViewController];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"interstitial Ad wasn't ready");
    }
}
@end

And here is my attempt with rewarded ads:
@interface adRewarded : NSObject
/// The interstitial ad.
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADRewardedAd *rewarded;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GADRequest *request;
@end

@implementation adRewarded

-(id)init {
    [self createAndLoadRewarded];
    NSLog(@"adRewarded init");
    return self;
}

- (void)createAndLoadRewarded {
    self.rewarded = [[GADRewardedAd alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"]; // test id
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
    self.rewarded.delegate = self;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID, @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a" ];
    [self.rewarded loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"createAndLoadRewarded");
}

- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADRewardedAd *)ad {
    //  Method for reloading the object so that you can show ads again
    NSLog(@"rewardedWillDismissScreen");
    [self createAndLoadRewarded];
}

- (void)RewardedView {  // show interstitial ADS
    if (self.rewarded.isReady) {
        NSLog(@"Show rewarded ADS!");
        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
        [self.rewarded presentFromRootViewController:rootViewController];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"rewarded Ad wasn't ready");
    }
}
@end

And I obtain an error on the line : self.rewarded.delegate = self;
The error is : Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'GADRewardedAd'
Just for info to start the ad in Python I am using the following code:
from pyobjus import autoclass
current_ad = autoclass("adInterstitial").alloc().init()
current_ad.show()

I also tried to use the Google documentation https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded#objective-c to create a new version but I struggle with the object named ViewController.
Either I get this error if I just copy paste the example:
Cannot find interface declaration for ViewController; did you mean UIViewController
or I get this error if I replace with UIViewController:
Cannot synthesize weak property in file using manual reference counting
Would you please know how to solve it ?
Thank you in advance!
Edit
After changing the code to :
@interface adRewarded : NSObject
/// The interstitial ad.
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADRewardedAd *rewarded;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GADRequest *request;
@end

@implementation adRewarded

-(id)init {
    [self createAndLoadRewarded];
    NSLog(@"adRewarded init");
    return self;
}

- (void)createAndLoadRewarded {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [GADRewardedAd loadWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313"
                            request:request
                  completionHandler:^(GADRewardedAd * _Nullable rewardedAd, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Rewarded ad failed to load with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                      return;
        }
        self.rewarded = rewardedAd;
        NSLog(@"Rewarded ad loaded");
    }];
}

- (void)presentRewardAd {
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;

    //Present reward ad over current controller
    [self.rewarded presentFromRootViewController:rootViewController userDidEarnRewardHandler:^{
        //TODO:
    }];
}

- (void)rewardedWillDismissScreen:(GADRewardedAd *)ad {
    //  Method for reloading the object so that you can show ads again
    NSLog(@"rewardedWillDismissScreen");
    [self createAndLoadRewarded];
}

- (void)RewardedView {  // show interstitial ADS
    if (self.rewarded.isReady) {
        NSLog(@"Show rewarded ADS!");
        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;
        [self.rewarded presentFromRootViewController:rootViewController];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"rewarded Ad wasn't ready");
    }
}
@end
// End


I obtain the following error message :
try to load ad
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[GADRewardedAd loadWithAdUnitID:request:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103354520'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004cd571 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff8000837e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004e24fc _CFAutoreleasePoolAddObject + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004d1d04 ___forwarding___ + 1459
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8004d3f08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   linconym                            0x0000000101f73432 -[adRewarded createAndLoadRewarded] + 130
    6   linconym                            0x0000000101f73391 -[adRewarded init] + 33
    7   linconym                            0x0000000102179b62 ffi_call_unix64 + 82
    8   ???                                 0x0000600000018cb0 0x0 + 105553116368048
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException


GADRewardedAd is different than GADInterstitial. You can check the documentation here. There is no delegate within this class, it only had fullScreenContentDelegate for handling full screen content.
You need to load the ad first, then present it with presentFromRootViewController:
- (void)createAndLoadRewarded {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [GADRewardedAd loadWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"
                            request:request
                  completionHandler:^(GADRewardedAd * _Nullable rewardedAd, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        self.rewarded = rewardedAd;
    }];
}

- (void)presentRewardAd {
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = window.rootViewController;

    //Present reward ad over current controller
    [self.rewarded presentFromRootViewController:rootViewController userDidEarnRewardHandler:^{
        //TODO:
    }];
}

It worked well with your UnitID above. Output:


Thank you very much for your help @sonle!
Unfortunately I get a new error message :
Exception NSException * "+[GADRewardedAd loadWithAdUnitID:request:completionHandler:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1085cd4e0" 0x0000600000cab180
Do you know what went wrong ?

Did the GADRewardedAd in completion block load successfully or it's NULL?

I don't know yet, I will perform new tests on friday.

Hello I have checked the GADRewardedAdand it is neither NULL or loaded, the function just crashes before having time to load it. Here is a more detailed error message, sorry the previous one was not enough.
See edit section.

Hi @sonle, would you please have an idea of what is wrong ? I am stuck here...

From my perspective, I thought it was about your init function. Can you remove createAndLoadRewarded from init, then public this function and call it later? i.e, from viewDidLoad of a view controller life cycle.
